# DFP refresh ads including settargeting on async event

Tags: refresh, google-dfp

I know I can refresh slot by calling `window.googletag.pubads().refresh();`
Now I'd like to refresh the ad, with new settargeting(s). Is it possible? What would be the best practise?

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible to refresh an AdUnit. 
First on the define slot define set it to a variable:

```
var slot1 = googletag.pubads().display('/1234567/sports', [728, 90], 'div-1');
```

after that, when you want to refresh it just call:

```
googletag.pubads().refresh(slot1);
```

You can also pass new targetings (globally) using:

```
googletag.pubads().setTargeting('interests', 'sports');
```

to set new targeting for each AdUnit or:

```
slot1.setTargeting('interests', 'sports');
```

to set targeting for the previous slot (defined by slot 1).